# How to show !equals in if statement (Java)?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, equals

How is it possible to show if it's not equal (`!=`, something like this maybe) in an `if` statement?

For example:

```
for (int g = 0; g < doglist.size(); g++){
    if(doglist.get(g).equals(name)){
        System.out.println("There is no dog with that name: ");
    }
}
```

So in this code I want to print the message if the entry in the list is not equal to name. So instead of `equals(name)` I'll have to use something different. How is this possible?

Comment: Hi Nanabua, welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [answer]. Your question is good, so you don't need to do anything to fix it.

Comment: Are you asking for code to show when there are no dogs in the list that have a name property equal to the given name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the NOT operator `!` with appropriate parentheses for clarity (though not strictly required).

```
if (!(condition))
```

so in your case....

```
if(!(doglist.get(g).equals(name)))
```

Comment: beat me to the punch bet yes this works great and cuts down on code

Comment: you also need to make sure doglist.get(g) is not null in some way, because else you'd throw a nullpointerexception.

Comment: Just to make sure there's no confusion: The parenthesis around the condition aren't strictly necessary though advisable.

Comment: The `()` around `doglist...` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
if (!doglist.get(g).equals(name))
```

About your idea of using `!=`: For primitive data types, yes, it's correct to test equality using `!=`.  `.equals()` is for object data types.  However, applying != to an object would be testing whether the memory location of the operands is the same, which is not the relevant information.  `.equals()` is what tests for whether the objects are actually equal.

For example, when comparing `int`s (a primitive type), you would use `!=`:

```
int a = 0, b = 1;
if (a != b) doSomething(); //Calls the method
```

Primitive types do not recognize the .equals() method at all.  But if you want to compare `String`s (an object type), you would use `!<object>.equals()`:

```
String s1 = "Hello", s2 = "World";
if (!s1.equals(s2)) doSomething(); //Calls the method
```

If you used `!=` with an object, it would compile, but likely would not produce the desired output:

```
String s1 = "Hello!";
String s2 = "Hello!"; //Make a new object with the same data -- contains "Hello!"
if (s1 != s2) doSomething(); //Will run doSomething(), even though s1.equals(s2)
```

Comment: Actually, this will work -- the code will get JIT'd and both `s1` and `s2` will point to the same object. Please revert that bit.